# Python How to get Scrapy Xpath data from Basic Table?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

```
<TABLE>
<br>

    <TR>
    <td width = 270><p align="left" style="margin-left: 0;"><b>Info</b></p></td>
    <td><p>  </p></td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <td width = 270><p align="left" style="margin-left: 10;">Page&nbsp;Count</p></td>
    <td><p> =  4 </p></td>
    </TR>
    ...
```

Trying to get a response.xpath for the `= 4` value from the table above. Even when inspecting the element in Chrome and pulling the xpath that way I sill end up with a [] value. Tried:

```
/html/body/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2] 
//table[2]/tr[2]/td[2]
```

both fails.

Comment: With the limited snippet of HTML you showed, it's impossible to know why it failed. Why did you try both `[1]` and `[2]` as the table element's position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get the `td` by `Count` text instead and then get the `following-sibling`:

```
//td[contains(p, "Count")]/following-sibling::td/p/text()
```

Demo:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: response.xpath('//td[contains(p, "Count")]/following-sibling::td/p/text()').extract()
Out[1]: [u' = 4 ']
```

And if you want to extract the actual number, use [`.re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions):

```
In [2]: response.xpath('//td[contains(p, "Count")]/following-sibling::td/p/text()').re(r'(\d+)')
Out[2]: [u'4']
```